# Symfony: type error when using flash bag in controller

Tags: php, symfony, session, typeerror

In order to get the flash bag of the session and add a flash message, in the controller I call:

`$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->addFlash(...);`

(where `$request` is an instance of [Request](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html))

but I get the following IDE type error:

> Method 'getFlashBag' not found in
>   null|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$request->getSession()` returns a [SessionInterface](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.html), which does not contain the `getFlashBag` method.

That's why the IDE is complaining, even if the actual object returned by that method is an instance of the [Session](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html) class which has the `getFlashBag` method.

When inside a controller, a quick solution can just be using:

`$this->addFlash(...);`

instead of:

`$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->addFlash(...);`